# Having issues sending specific stylesheets to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

No matter what I do, IE will not display my website. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how I can go about fixing this. If anyone can help, please. I have been stumped on this for days

I am creating my first HTML5 website and of course with a the new territory there is more to learn. [My website here](http://www.ambergoodwin.com/dev/index-fluid.html) works well in all browsers and devices that I know of so far and I'm using CSS3 media queries to send the information I want when the screen is at specific size.

Now of course IE doesn't support this feature so I'm using conditional comments to see if it is IE and if it is use my ie.css styles. However I have to be laying it our wrong cause it's either not working (nothing shows up on the page and then crashes) or it shows the mobile styles on the full size window! I have tried to use the respond.js file AND the css3-mediaqueries.js file and they have not worked for me. This is the last thing in my way stopping me from getting this site up and after struggling with why it does not work I'm getting desperate to find a solution.

This is the bottom part of my head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-fluid.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" />

<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

So I'm not sure what I a m doing wrong to have this happen. I've wanted to use media queries for a while now and I know there is a way to use them and just tell IE to use this style sheet instead?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are a very talented site (and business card) designer!

Comment: Haha. I very much appreciate that. You should check back in a week. I'll hopefully have it all up and running once I can figure this problem out. ;)

Comment: A question - maybe a bone headed one, bear with me - with your layering are your IE.css files layering/replacing/augmenting what shows up in your initial css? Or are you doing a full replacement?

Comment: Just changing some colours and sizes mostly.

Comment: which IE versions do you need to handle in a special way? IE7 and down or 8 and down?

Comment: Why are you including the same `ie.css` file three times? You only need one conditional comment, not three of them...

Comment: The page crashes in older versions of IE. What makes you think that the `ie.css` file is causing that?

Comment: @Sime Vidas: I seen it done on another website so I was using that method, however even if I target just IE or just IE 8 it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Amber Does the page crash if you remove all external CSS files from the page? My suggestion would be to exclude all external scripts and style sheets one-by-one, and check after each excluded resource if the page still crashes in IE. That way you would be able to identify the problematic file.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: That seems like a plan. Will be doing it first thing in the morning and comment back with results.

Answer (score 2):

at first i though its the top of you head... when you declate  you have this strange commenting markup, which i think i causing problems, and not rendering your later IF IE properly.  change
 `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->`   to
 `<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->`

but i've been testing it out on a different server and that doesnt seem to bother it.
would you consider the server this is being run on as the issue?  it seems like you tried quite a few things..

try my first suggestion, and check out http://tinyurl.com/87maskt in ie and not ie..
[i just c&p from the source and the reference here.  if you want you can send me the actual front page code to test there.]

best of luck!

Comment: Well I've never had a server issue. I'm with Go Daddy and have been using their services for many years on top of using them for other clients

It works perfect in FF or mac and windows and actually shows up properly in IE but after it loads it crashes. I'm not sure that means. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43287957/i-hate-IE.png If I wanted to give you my front page code, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: oh it crashed ie?  that's strange but leads me to think that it might be your install?   curiously, in the page i modified, it is suppose to mention the version for IE after the huge IE, but for you it doesnt...   and for me IE didnt crash at all while viewing it..    can you send me the code here? are there PMs on stackoverflow?

Comment: I'll use dropbox. It seems to work. Here is what you'll need and maybe more. But if you could help me figure this problem out that would be amazing! I've been working on this for too long now. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43287957/amberGoodwin.zip Let me know what you get it and I'll take it down.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for this too. I have no clue how to go about this without the effort from others. I'm away from the computer for a bit today but will be back later to figure this thing out.

Comment: the code you sent me doesnt actually have the ie.css part in it......           anyways --http://tinyurl.com/7ynxha2   and tell me whats up.

Comment: It should.... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43287957/ie.css That recent link still crashes IE. :S

Comment: try that last link again.. i disabled some js so it wont show properly but will help find out..

Comment: Well it works a bit better and at least doesn't crash! Does mean something we can work with?

Comment: yep.  that was without respond.js and modernizr, please check again now for only modernizr!

Comment: also coult you please mention which ie you are using, AND try to get the error msg before the crash?  you can do that by click on the yellow triagle at the bottom left, and quickly print screen....

Comment: It still crashes..I'm using IE 8 and I'm not able to click on the yellow triangle at the bottom, it freezes up on me.

Comment: When the page comes up a pop up windows displays saying that the page can not load and needs to close. Then I click "Don't Send" for the error report and then the page is fine. It works but of course the media queries dont. Not sure whats going on. Anyways, I wish to award you half my stated reputation points as this bounty is almost over and if you can continue to help me I'll somehow get you the other points hopefully. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: wow thanks for the points - soon ill be able to 'talk in chat'...! and maybe even buy some cheese.  =]       ill try to keep helping you. ========= so actually, after you click "don't send", you should be able to click the yellow marker for the message.  can you printscreen/transcribe it?

Comment: Haha. Well out of everyone at that point you kept on the problem. I have a few more options I will be trying from new thoughts from yesterday but I did what you told me to do but there is no triangle error. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43287957/done.png

Comment: boom!!   ,,,,,,,,,,,yeah, i've been doing some more reading, and it seems that the problem you [i wrote "we"] had was a bug when using both modernizr and respond.js============ in any case, i'd recommend you to update to the new boilerplate before you publish..   [!]

Comment: so download the new boilerplate and place my html code in that one and your saying it'll work?

Comment: Very sorry. No it didn't work. I've decided to start from scratch and have a fixed layout for now so I can at least get my site up and figure out why nothing seems to work for me when it comes to IE and fluid layouts. Currently I've been busy with some upcoming deadlines for designs so this is now on a back burner.. I appreciate all your help and time into this matter, hence why I voted you to receive at least half the awarded points as you took the most time to help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is there because you have no where in your css given type. You should have set the type as `text/css`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the stylesheets.. it's your html tag...

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Can I ask why???? That's really unnecessary.

Comment: I believe that was an earlier attempt at trying to fix why this was happening. I completely forgot about it. I have taken it out, yet I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it. Remove the @media print section from your ie.css.

Comment: I downloaded your entire site and opened it in IE. it crashed as expected. As soon as I removed the media print from your ie.css, the site came up as it should. Weird that didn't work for you. I'll take another look.

Comment: Here is your site sans images and the media print http://mattoettinger.com/test/amber/

Comment: It pretty late here now but I'll be working on this first thing tomorrow. Will comment back with more thought as to what I might be doing then.

Comment: I tested it out in IE8 through with VMWare Fusion but it looks the same. Just of course with now images. It's displaying the CSS mobile version. Maybe I've moved some things around but nothing I do seems to work to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do:

1. Update your HTML tag to utilize conditional comments as done in the HTML5 boilerplate. Scott's answer provides the snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153257/230649
2. Add respond.js to your project to get support for media queries in IE: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

If respond.js works you won't need to worry about your IE stylesheet and you can avoid it all together.

Now here's the kicker: your IE stylesheet has the HTML5 boilerplate reset included in it. You need to get rid of this. The only thing you should include in your IE specific stylesheet are the minor adjustments you want to make with text sizes, etc.

BUT hopefully you won't need to use this IE specific stylesheet at all if respond.js supports your media queries. I'd try removing the IE specific stylesheet and implementing respond.js to solve your issues.

Comment: It pretty late here now but I'll be working on this first thing tomorrow. This sound great so I'm stoked to try it out and get this problem fixed tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: It's coming back to me. I tried this is the begining btu I was hoping that maybe I didn't have the proper HTML Boiler plate head tag however I've tried the technique with the respond script and for some reason it's crashing in IE. Everyone says this script is so  great yet I cant get respond OR css3-media queries scripts to work??

It's uploaded, maybe you could check it out and see whats going on?

Comment: @Amber - I can't really isolate the problem on your page. There's a lot of moving parts there - your queries are a bit complex -- maybe more complex than respond.js allows for but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE **7**]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>**<!-->** <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Remove the comment from your last if statement and change the first 7 if statement too 6 as well as remove the double if statements for 8

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `class=` attribute in the `<html>` tag into the `<body>` tag and changing the `css` to select against the `<body>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> <body class="ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <body class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...Why don't you use Javascript to find out if they are using Internet Explorer, and if they are, redirect them to another home page that imports ie.css:

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-fluid.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        parent.location = "ie.php";
    }
}

</script>
```

**ie.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if !(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        parent.location = "index.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

Problem solved! Hope this helps!